# How should I connect a Wink relay when two circuits are involved?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I'm installing a Wink relay that has two switches for lights. The double gang box I want to install it in also has two switches that are operating lights only. My problem is that each light is on a different circuit breaker.

The Wink relay has only one line in and two loads out. Can I switch one of the lights to the other's circuit and leave a hot line in the box with a wire nut?

Comment: Probably, but might depend on how the lights are wired. Please post a clear photo of the box or a sketch of the connections.

Answer (score 1):

It is always safe to leave a hot wire capped off with a wire nut. However (as Harper says), you must also disconnect and cap off the corresponding neutral wire.

Find and remove the wire nut connecting the neutral that you want to discontinue. Having separated the wires, cap off the one leading to the circuit breaker. Connect the one from the light to the neutral wire nut that will remain in use.

[image: modification for Wink 2-load control]
fig.1a, left: Existing circuits; fig.1b, right: Modification for Wink 2-load control.

You should add up the total loads on each of the two circuit breakers, and power the switch from the one with the lighter load. The illustration assumes that the power feed on the right was from the more heavily loaded breaker.

You might consider leaving a label "no longer needed" taped to the wires, but that is not required, and any future maintainer who sees the two loads and the double gang box will not be horribly confused by what you did.

Comment: Not a single wire, if he wants to deprecate a connection, he needs to do the same with both hot and neutral.  if you are not religious about that, you will inevitably create a crossed-neutral situation with potential for fire and maddening incompatibility with AFCI or GFCI.

Comment: @Harper: You are correct. This is a serious omission. I will modify my answer.